# WPF Datagrid with SQL data, order colomns

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with data in it from a SQL database (WPF application),

```
PRCEntities vPRCEntities = new PRCEntities();

var All = from a in vPRCEntities.tblCars
         select a;

myDataGrid_Cars.ItemsSource = All;
```

Thats works so far,

If i put CanUserReorderColumns="True" and CanUserSortColumns="True", then I can click the colomn header but it doesn't sort the collumns itself.

Is there a way to order that?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have AutoGenerateColumns="False" and your Columns set up like:

```
<my:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ColumnName}" Header="Column Name" />
```

Comment: Can you try: var All = (from a in vPRCEntities.tblCars select a).ToList(); Maybe you can copy your grid xaml for us to see?